# How can I print two commands on remote server in the same line?

Tags: linux, bash

When I'm trying to print in the console the output of this command
`ssh 192.168.1.120 'df -h | grep sda2; hostname;'` I get this

```
/dev/sda2        23G  8.0G   14G  38% /
localhost
```

while I would like to see this

```
/dev/sda2        23G  8.0G   14G  38% / localhost
```

Although I can print these in the same line with the following way

```
result=`ssh 192.168.1.120 'df -h | grep sda2; hostname;'`
echo $result
```

It is not what I want, since this way does not preserve the actual spaces between the characters.

Is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually ppl just use the fact, that command substitution removes trailing newlines.

```
ssh 192.168.1.120 'echo $(df -h | grep sda2) $(hostname)'
```

In your case, you can also postprocess it.

```
ssh ... | paste -sd' '
ssh ... | tr -d '\n'
```

Remove newline from one command:

```
ssh ... 'df -h | grep sda2 | tr -d "\\n" ; hostname'
```

Prefer `$(...)` over backticks `. Check your scripts with shellcheck.

Comment: Thanks man, `ssh ... 'df -h | grep sda2 | tr -d "\n" ; hostname'` solved my problem